# Java 8 Split a stream into multiple streams of the same size (deck of cards)

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17

I'm using JavaSE-17

A - I have 3 things :

(1) A list of n cards, say:

```
List<Card> cards;                      // where Card is a Record
Interger numberOfCards = cards.size(); // Usually cards.size() == 52
```

(2) A number of players, say:

```
Integer numberOfPlayers;
```

(3) A number of cards to deal to each player, say:

```
Integer numberOfCardsPerPlayer;
```

Assuming :

- Each player receive the same number of card (`numberOfCardsPerPlayer`).
- `numberOfCardsPerPlayer * numberOfPlayers <= numberOfCards`

B - I want to get a list containing `numberOfPlayers` lists of cards where each list of cards contains exactly `numberOfCardsPerPlayer` cards.

For example, if I have a deck of 52 cards, 3 players and 5 cards per player, I should get a list of 3 lists of cards with each list of cards contains 5 cards.

C - Question

Is there a way of doing it without the `AtomicInteger` and without calling `stream` two times? (and without using loops or external librairies).

D - The code below works but feels strange (using `AtomicInteger` feels like cheating because I try to avoid mutability and I'm not sure calling `stream` two times is good practice)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DeckOfCards {
    public enum Suit {CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE}
    public enum Value {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN}

    public record Card(Suit suit,  Value value) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer numberOfPlayers = 3;
        Integer numberOfCardsPerPlayer = 2;
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>(
                Arrays.asList(new Card(Suit.CLUB, Value.TWO),
                        new Card(Suit.DIAMOND, Value.SIX),
                        new Card(Suit.HEART, Value.FOUR),
                        new Card(Suit.SPADE, Value.SEVEN),
                        new Card(Suit.HEART, Value.FIVE),
                        new Card(Suit.CLUB, Value.FOUR),
                        new Card(Suit.SPADE, Value.THREE)
                        )
                );

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        List<List<Card>> result = 
                cards.stream()
                .limit(numberOfCardsPerPlayer * numberOfPlayers)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> counter.getAndIncrement() / numberOfCardsPerPlayer))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(result);
        // Prints :
        // [
        //   [Card[suit=CLUB, value=TWO], Card[suit=DIAMOND, value=SIX]]
        // , [Card[suit=HEART, value=FOUR], Card[suit=SPADE, value=SEVEN]]
        // , [Card[suit=HEART, value=FIVE], Card[suit=CLUB, value=FOUR]]
        // ]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. I am using a record to simulate cards as as simple integer.

- First stream the number of players via `IntStream`.
- then create a `subList` taking the proper number of cards for each player.
- the above is `mapped` to place each new "hand" on the stream.
- then return each `hand` in list of lists.

```
record Card(int a) {
}

Integer numberOfPlayers = 3;
Integer numberOfCardsPerPlayer = 5;
List<Card> cards = IntStream.range(0, numberOfPlayer*numberOfCardsPerPlayer).mapToObj(i -> new Card(i))
        .toList();

 List<List<Card>> hands = IntStream.range(0, numberOfPlayers)
                .<List<Card>>mapToObj(player -> new ArrayList<>(
                        cards.subList(player * numberOfCardsPerPlayer,
                                (player + 1) * numberOfCardsPerPlayer)))
                .toList();

hands.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[Card[a=0], Card[a=1], Card[a=2], Card[a=3], Card[a=4]]
[Card[a=5], Card[a=6], Card[a=7], Card[a=8], Card[a=9]]
[Card[a=10], Card[a=11], Card[a=12], Card[a=13], Card[a=14]]
```

The reason I add the `subList` as an argument to `ArrayList` is because a subList provided a view of the original list.  So if you alter a subList, you change the original list.   Creating a new `ArrayList` makes the `sublist` independent.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry, my original question didn't provide a testable piece of code and it forced you to generate the list of cards yourself. Even if it's to late I updated my question and made my code fully testable and, of course, you solution still works. Thank you!

Comment: @hubert BTW. something that might be of use to you is [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm already using it. I considered for 2 seconds generating a randomly shuffled deck of cards the functional way with Java but I quickly gave up, exhausted I was after painfully producing the cartesian product between Suit and Value to get the unshuffled deck of cards.